# How to rewrite this grammar for LL(1) parsing?

Tags: parsing, language-design, ll-grammar, recursive-descent

I am trying to write a top-down recursive-descent parser for a small language, and I am facing some issues with the assignment statements. Here is the grammar from the language specifications:

```
<assign_stmt> ::= <lvalue> <l_tail> ":=" <expr> ";"

<l_tail> ::= ":=" <lvalue> <l_tail>
           | ""

<expr> ::= ....  
     #multiple layers betwen <expr> and <lvalue>, like <term>, <factor>, etc.
     #in the end, <expr> can be a <lvalue>
         | <lvalue>
```

so that the assignments can look like

```
a := b := 3;
c := d := e := f;
```

The grammar does not seem to be ambiguous, but it is causing me issues because `<expr>` can itself be a `<lvalue>`. When parsing `<l_tail>`, both production rules are equally valid and I don't know which one to pick. I tried various left-factorizations (see below), but so far, I have not been able to find a `LL(1)` grammar that works for me. Is it even possible here?

```
<assign_stmt> ::= <lvalue> ":=" <rest> 

<rest> ::= <expr> ";"
         | <lvalue> ":=" <l_tail>
```

Note that I could go around this issue by parsing `<l_tail>` and then looking for the `";"` token. Depending on the result, I would know whether the last `<lvalue>` was actually an `<expr>` or not (without having to backtrack). However, I am learning here, and I would like to know the "right" way to overcome this problem.